# IsIndeterminate ProgressBar Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I got  following `ProgressBar` style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ActiveControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"
                      MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Indicator"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush>Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Track"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="True">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_GlowRect"
                                Width="100"
                                Background="{StaticResource ActiveControlBorderBrush}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Margin="-100,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I set `IsIndeterminate` to `True` on `ProgressBar`; I can see `Indicator` moving in `designer` but not on `runtime`. Anyone knows why it's not working on `runtime`?

**EDIT:**

using Visual Studio Professional 2012 / Application is WPF .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example and it seems to work. Check that:

1. StaticResources found correctly, i've used Black instead of ActiveControlBorderBrush and Green instead of ControlBackground.
2. Check for the possible threading issues (it can frezee  or smth) if you are showing it from code.

Comment: Empty `window` with only `progressbar` and this style in `resourcedictionary`. Window is not freezing. Strange is; it's working in designer.

Comment: Well, the stupid question: do you have IsIntermediate property set to true? :) Does it work without the style?

Comment: Yeah :) ofc it's set. As I said; it's working in `designer` but not on `runtime`. Tried moving style out of `resourcedictionary`. Tried replacing `VSM` with `trigger`. Default `progressbar` without `style` is working.

Comment: This is weird cause i see it working for me. I've used VS 2012 with WPF 4.0 you can try to check this issue with different .NET version.